# Number of people so that there is at least a 50% chance of a birthday on everyday

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Assuming that people's birthdays are uniformly distributed across the 365 days in the year, how many people would you need such that the probability of there being at least one birthday in the crowd for every day of the year is 50%?

Comment: Interesting question! What are your thoughts on it?

Comment: Considering people and birthdays to be indistinguishable, then the number of ways n people can have birthdays such that every birthday is covered is (n-1) C 364 (see stars and bars). The total number of ways people can have birthdays is 365^n. (n-1 C 364)/365^n will only equal .5 with 0<n<1... so it's impossible?

Comment: Good start.  But you're not counting the “at least” part in the problem.  Maybe think about it the other way around; how many ways can $N$ people have birthdays that miss exactly $k$ days?

Comment: I found a similar question. This is the coupon collection problem. We need at least 2287 people.